# C# MEF Hangs when creating DirectoryCatalog

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, mef

I'm running into a problem with MEF where it's hanging when creating the DirectoryCatalog.  I have a Windows Forms application that I test the MEF functionality, and it works without a problem.  However, when I run the same code in a Windows Service, it hangs on the line:

```
_catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(assemblyBaseDirectory);


//Here is the full code block. 
var codeBaseDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);

if (codeBaseDir != null) {
    assemblyBaseDirectory = new Uri(codeBaseDir).AbsolutePath;
    Logger.Info("Creating Directory Catalog for " + assemblyBaseDirectory);
    _catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(assemblyBaseDirectory);
    Logger.Info("Directory Catalog created!");

}
```

I don't get an exception either. I put the logging in and found the the second Logger.Info line never gets called.

**UPDATE:**

I determined that my path was not returned the same when I called this code from my service.  It was formatting the directory path as "C:/Program%20Files/My%20Service".  I'm not sure why it wasn't doing this for my win forms app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first thing you need to look at is the differences between running a Windows application (as yourself), and then a Windows service (as what?). Also, the startup directory for windows services is `C:\Windows\System32` which is where `svchost.exe` runs from.  The way I resolve startup paths when using services, is to wrap a call to the `Uri` class to grab the local path:

```
var path = new Uri(typeof(Something).Assembly.Location).LocalPath;
var catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(path);
```

Can you verify that the service user has access to the same path?

Comment: The service is running under the Local System account.  I checked the path using the code you've provided and it returns the same path as I'm getting from my code. It's the path where I've installed my service. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: After looking at this site for other peoples issues with MEF and directory permissions, it appears as if they get an exception when there is a security issue.